# How can I make a List(main) of Lists of Objects correctly so that when an item is added to a list, it is not added to all the lists in the List(main)?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, serialization

I have this:

```
public sealed class RepositoryContacts
{
     public List<List<Template>> Contacts = new List<List<Template>>();

     public List<Template> PersonalContacts = new List<Template>();
     public static RepositoryContactacts Instancia = new RepositoryContactacts();
     private RepositoryContacts() { }
}
```

Suppose I added two Listings in Contacts, something like this:

```
PlantillaContactos contact = new PlantillaContactos 
{
    Name= "",
    LastName= "",
    Address= "",
};
RepositoryContacts.Instancia.PersonalContacts.Add(contact);
            
RepositoryContacts.Instancia.Contacts.Add(RepositoryContacts.Instancia.PersonalContacts);
RepositoryContacts.Instancia.PersonalContacts.Clear();
RepositoryContacts.Instancia.Contacts[RepositoryContacts.Instancia.Contacts.Count - 1].Clear();
```

All good so far, the last two lines are to clean up the content of the lists since it was initialized inside Contacts. Now when I really want to add an item to a list, they are added in all the lists it has inside. This is what I do:

```
public void Add(string name, string lastname, string address) 
{
    PlantillaContactos contacto = new PlantillaContactos 
    {
        Name= name,
        LastName= lastname,
        Address= address,
    };
    RepositoryContacts.Instancia.PersonalContacts.Add(contacto);
    RepositoryContacts.Instancia.Contactos[index] = RepositoryContacts.Instancia.PersonalContacts;
}
```

The value of the variable "index", will vary depending on the list you want to get (I already tested it).

Note: I will create all this for your next serialization.

Comment: Question reads in an odd way; is it homework/written by another person?

Comment: I've fixed it as much as I could, it's translated, but if you still can't understand it, let me know.

Comment: I think you should clear your mind about your implementation problem :( not clear!

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You used the **Singleton** Pattern Design and changed it to just one example

`RepositoryContacts` change to :

```
public sealed class RepositoryContacts
{
    public List<List<Template>> Contacts = new List<List<Template>>();
    public List<Template> PersonalContacts = new List<Template>();
    
    private static RepositoryContactacts instancia = null;
    private RepositoryContacts() { }
    public static RepositoryContactacts Instancia
    {
        get
        {
            if (instancia == null)
            {
               instancia = new RepositoryContactacts();
            }
            return instancia;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why do you think that your proposed solution might solve OP's problem?